# Write a query to display list of employees having salary greater than Max salary define for respective JOB_ID

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

These are 2 tables with common  `job_id` column.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask carefully

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this (presuming table names are `emp` and `job`):

```
select e.employee_id
from emp e
where e.salary > (select j.max_salary
                  from job j
                  where j.job_id = e.job_id
                 );
```